# How to optimize css style for Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I had a problem with the correct display of css3 styles on Safari. Here is a link to my code: https://codepen.io/VictorHub/pen/NmYOGj There are transparent stroke text over image. Everything works well but not in Safari browser(There appears a black background in the letters). Naturally we are talking about the latest versions of the Safari browser. Please help me solve this issue. The situation is complicated by the fact that I do not have macos.

```css
html {
  background: #fff;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://medievaltorturemuseum.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/slide3-1.jpg')
}

.text-wrap {
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  position: absolute;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgb(12, 12, 12);
  font-size: 98px;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(170,26,24,1) 0%, rgba(213,44,50,1) 39%, rgba(236,97,94,1) 45%, rgba(202,34,34,1) 69%, rgba(148,36,43,1) 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px transparent;
    letter-spacing: -4px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(208,34,40,1);
    animation-name: blink2;
    animation-duration: 150ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}


@keyframes blink2 {
0% {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(208,34,40,1);
}
  
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(208,34,40,0.75);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-wrap">
  <div class="text">ARE YOU BRAVE<br/>ENOUGH ?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't have MacOS, how do you know it doesn't display as intended in Safari? It doesn't display as intended in the last version of Safari for Windows, but that's 7 years old now. Support for [mix-blend-mode](https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode) was added more recently, in Safari 7.1 (or 8?). Also MS Edge hasn't implemented that property yet.

Comment: I know it because my client demonstrate this on his MacOS laptop with laest Safari version. I know that mix-blend-mode have to worck on latest version of Safari but facts - in a particular case it does not work. And if you have an opportunity you can see it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
  background: #fff;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://medievaltorturemuseum.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/slide3-1.jpg')
}

.text-wrap {
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  position: absolute;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgb(12, 12, 12);
  font-size: 98px;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(170,26,24,1) 0%, rgba(213,44,50,1) 39%, rgba(236,97,94,1) 45%, rgba(202,34,34,1) 69%, rgba(148,36,43,1) 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px transparent;
    letter-spacing: -4px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(208,34,40,1);
    animation-name: blink2;
    animation-duration: 150ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}


@keyframes blink2 {
0% {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(208,34,40,1);
}
  
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(208,34,40,0.75);
  }
}


@-webkit-keyframes blink2 {
0% {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(208,34,40,1);
}
  
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(208,34,40,0.75);
  }
}


@-moz-keyframes blink2 {
0% {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(208,34,40,1);
}
  
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(208,34,40,0.75);
  }
}


@-o-keyframes blink2 {
0% {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(208,34,40,1);
}
  
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(208,34,40,0.75);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-wrap">
  <div class="text">ARE YOU BRAVE<br/>ENOUGH ?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem might be with vendor prefix for keyframes...tried in safari - Win, works.